# How can I detect AJAX calls using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe

Basically, I have an iframe of a page from another domain, and I want to detect when the page sends an Ajax call. So if the iframe sends an Ajax request, my script would fire a function.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can't access the javascript of another domain. Do you own both domains?

Comment: You can't, there's no way violate cross origin restrictions in the browser, which are there specifically to avoid developers from one site from sniffing whatever the other site is doing inside their own iframe.

Comment: Well if you control both back end systems you could do it, though it seems kind-of insane.

Comment: Actually if he controls both domains and doesn't need to support IE7 or lesser browsers, then he could get his way by communicating via `postMessage` between both frames. You are still unable to sniff, but you can publish to the other domain whatever you decide is worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only can do this using:

Use the **document.domain** : i dont recommend, but its one possibility

Configure the header of request (ex: in apache) with **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**, but it only works on modern browsers